# Node.js websocket unhandeled error events.js websocket.js

Tags: node.js, websocket

I am using express webserver with node.js and the standard websocket require('ws');

Now it happens sometimes when internet connection is lost, i think that is the main reason when this happen, i am getting then a error message and the script stops to run:

> events.js:287
> throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
> ^
>
> Error: read ECONNRESET
> at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:205:27) Emitted 'error' event on WebSocket instance at:
> at WebSocket.finalize (C:\Users\ABC\Desktop\Websocket\node_modules\ws\lib\WebSocket.js:182:41)
> at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:310:20)
> at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
> at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {   errno: 'ECONNRESET',
> code: 'ECONNRESET',   syscall: 'read' }

In the websocket client code i have also write a console.log or error events, see my code below:

```
ws.on('message', function incoming(data)
      {
        const obj = JSON.parse(data);   
        console.log("Stream: "+obj["k"].s+"  "+obj["k"].i+"  closeprice "+obj["k"].c+"\n");
      });
ws.on('error', function(e){
            console.log("stream error "+e);
        });
```

the question is if i can do something to prevent this behavior? I normaly know that this problems happen when you dont console.log error events but for me it looks like i am doing that already. Maybe do i need to make changes in the ws module files?

Comment: You did mention listening on error on your client side (with shown code), but did you do it on the server side too?

Comment: which server side do you mean? I am only doing a websocket connection to somebody else  his server i dont deliver myself a websocket to public. the error text which i get is telling unhandeled error with events.js and/or websocket.js file, but that files are download with npm, normaly the libaries which i download with npm ont need to be change, i dont know currently where the unhandeled error comes from